# Tab без перезагрузки страницы, но с изменением URL в адресной строке

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать `tab`, чтобы при нажатии на один из пунктов таба страница не перезагружалась, но при этом URL менялся?

[Вот пример.](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/cms/editions/)

Здесь, если нажимать на кнопки `"Редакции"` и `"Сравнить"`, страница не перезагружается, а URL меняется. И соответственно, если скопировать этот URL и вставить в новую вкладку, то откроется эта же страница с тем табом который был нажат.

Вот код моего таба:

```
$(function(){
    $('#prod_tabs li').eq(0).addClass('active');
    $('#prod_blocks .pb').eq(0).addClass('active');
    $('#prod_tabs li').click(function(){
                alert(location.href);
        $('#prod_tabs li').removeClass('active');
        $('#prod_blocks .pb').removeClass('active');
        $('#prod_tabs li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
        $('#prod_blocks .pb').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: читайте про history api. ЗА ВАС ктото чтото будет делать только за плату.

Answer (score 5):

При клике на таб меняйте хэш, URL можно будет скопировать и открыть на нужном табе:

```
window.location.hash = 'tab1'
```

А при загрузке страницы проверяйте хэш и открывайте нужный таб:

```
if (window.location.hash != '') openTab(window.location.hash)
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, а не могли бы вы мне на мой скрипт приблизительно добавить как должно выглядеть

Comment: Нет, я достаточно написал для решения вашей задачи.